# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' error occurs when I try to get a heading of a docx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am new to python programming. I am using `docx` module to work with documents.
When I try to read a heading from docx file using `paragraph.style.name`, I am getting:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

***My Script:***

```
from docx import Document  
document=Document('C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\check\\Leave_Policy_converted.docx')
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name == 'Heading 1':
        print (paragraph.text)
```

Please clarify me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This basically means that `paragraph.style` returns `None`. You will need to check why, or simply handle that case separately, like `if paragraph.style: if paragraph.style.name == 'Heading 1':`

Comment: `paragraph.style` returns `None` when there is no style applied to the paragraph and no default paragraph style has been defined for the document.

Answer (score 1):

This means that something which you are accessing an attribute on is `None` (not a real value).

You need to check `paragraph.style` if it is `None`, and not access `.style.name`.

```
if paragraph.style is not None and paragraph.style.name == 'Heading 1':
  print(paragraph.text)
```